# Getting Error Updating Email/Password on Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having error on Firebase. When I am trying to enabled Email and Password for Authentication. I am getting error like "ERROR UPDATING EMAIL/PASSWORD". [image]

Comment: Try to enabled it on Incognito mode. It will work

Comment: Don't tag it as "SOLVED", instead add an answer and accept it. This is how Stack Overflow automatically flag as solved.

Comment: Can I upvote my own question? Is there any way I can answer on my own questions?

Comment: Just answer in the answer section below.

Comment: Take a look at the help guide here on SO [Can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: For those who are having the issue even after disabling the CORS extension, try using your phone to enable it. Try going to  firebase website from your phone and enable the email/password sign in feature. This method worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 62):

If you are using CORS extension, disable it and you will be fine!

Answer (score 13):

Try to to enable the Email/Password provider using an incognito window, or try using a different supported browser.

Verify if there are any other programs that might be blocking your connection such as antivirus, proxy or firewall. If yes, try to disable them.

Connect using a different network or machine

Comment: Enabling the Email/Password provider in incognito window worked.

Comment: Works for me as well. February 2022

Comment: I had CORS extension enabled. By disabling CORS extension. Problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Just disable the CORS extension from your browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To fix CORS issues in Firebase caused by email and password authentication, you might need to disable CORS extensions. CORS is a browser security feature that stops web pages from requesting data from different places. When you enable email and password authentication in Firebase, it can lead to CORS issues if your requests come from a different location (like a different website or port).To make it work, you may need to disable CORS extensions in your browser.